# How to Pass Variable and not values in URL in jsp page

Tags: jsp, url, url-parameters

I have a String called `var2="ASDFDE"` whose value keeps changing.
Now I want to pass this `variable(row_id)` in URL.
For that I may need to write

```
action=action.jsp?var1=var2
```

In the action jsp page when I retrieve the row

```
out.println("Row_ID from previous jsp page is: "+request.getParameter("var1"));
```

It prints out

Row_ID from previous jsp page is: var2 
whereas what I want is
Row_ID from previous jsp page is: ASDFDE

How do I do that? How do I just pass the variable through the URL without mentioning its value so that whatever would be the current value of that String is passed to next jsp page.

If it cannot be done through URL then what is the alternative. It would be really helpful if someone can explain with the example, I am new to this.

Comment: Sorry is just realized i typed wrong...Instead of (row_id) in the statemnt Now i want to pass this variable(row_id), it is (var2).My doubt is while passing value thru URL the snytax is 
 example?varname=constant or somevalue . WHat if instead of constanrt or somevalue i want to pass some variable

Comment: Sorry i just realized i have made my question so complicated.The jist is ...."Can i pass string var2  from one jsp page  through url to another jsp page.If not how can i do it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out how session works

```
session.setAtribute('var1','value');
String var1=session.getAtribute('var1') ;
```